# Nav using dot notation with react

Tags: javascript, react.js

Here I am trying to simplify my bootstrap name using dot notation, but I'm having lots of issues getting my nav to render different pages.

- Am I setting my routes properly?
- Am I setting the switch properly?
- Am I setting the `Link` properly?

I found most of my information [here](https://blog.pshrmn.com/simple-react-router-v4-tutorial/). I tried bringing in a switch on the `App.js` to help, and I tried bringing in a

## HeaderNav

```
import React from "react";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class HeaderNavigation extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <Nav
              activeKey="/home"
              onSelect={selectedKey => alert(`selected ${selectedKey}`)}
            >
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav> <Link to "/home">home</Link> Active </Nav>
              </Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Link</Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Link</Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey="disabled" disabled>
                  Disabled
                </Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
            </Nav>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

## main.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Roster from "./Roster";
import Schedule from "./Schedule";

// The Main component renders one of the three provided
// Routes (provided that one matches). Both the /roster
// and /schedule routes will match any pathname that starts
// with /roster or /schedule. The / route will only match
// when the pathname is exactly the string "/"
const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={Roster} />
      <Route path="/more" component={Schedule} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
);

export default Main;


import React from "react";
import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";
import main from "./src/main";
```

## App.js

```
    / Importing the Bootstrap CSS
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import HeaderNavigation from "../src/HeaderNavigation";
import Form from "../src/Form";
import Body from "../src/Body";



const App = () => (
  <>
    <>
      <HeaderNavigation className="body" />
      <Main />
    </>
    <Jumbotron fluid>
      <h1 className="header">Welcome To React-Bootstrap</h1>
    </Jumbotron>
    <Jumbotron fluid>
      <Form className="header" />
    </Jumbotron>
    <Body className="body" />
  </>
);

export default App;
```